# From $P(x;W) = \frac{1}{Z(W)} \exp \bigl[ \frac{1}{2} x^T W x \bigr]$ to Sigmoid

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, special-functions

In a book [chapter](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itprnn/ps/521.526.pdf) that talks about the Boltzmann distribution,

$$  
P(x;W) = \frac{1}{Z(W)} 
\exp \bigg[ \frac{1}{2} x^T W x \bigg]
$$

where $W$ is symmetric with zero diagonal. It makes a seque into a conditional probability definition where

$$ P(x_i = 1 | x_j, j \ne i) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-a_i}} $$

$$ a_i = \sum_j  w_{ij}x_j $$

How did the author make this jump from the original distribution, into one which uses the sigmoid (logistic) function? Some guesses are the conditional distribution written in this form

$$
P(x_1|x_j,i \ne j) = 
\frac{\frac{1}{Z} P(x_1,...,x_N)}{\frac{1}{Z} \sum_{x_i}P(x_1,...,x_N)} =
\frac{ P(x_1,...,x_N)}{\sum_{x_i}P(x_1,...,x_N)}
$$

$1/Z$'s would cancel out, and this could lead to the single sigmoid?

Any ideas?

Comment: "This question has not received enough attention." Could you be more specific?

Comment: Your answer is very concise and short; I wish I was able to understand it fully :( Factoring $e^{..}$ into pieces, or using $h$ whose definition is irrelevant, etc.

Comment: Just follow it closely and mention the first step which remains unclear. That is, unless you prefer to offer bounties without ever mentioning the problem you have with my answer...

Comment: ((Nice: the OP uses the old tactics of posting insulting comments and deleting them soon afterwards.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Haderlump

Let's define $x_i$ on $x$ being $b$ as $x^b$. Since

$$ P(x_j,j \ne i) = P(x^0) + P(x^1) $$

We can do

$$  P(x_i = 1 | x_j,j \ne i)  = \frac{P(x^1)}{P(x^0) + P(x^1)} $$

It's better to see $P(x^1)$ as divider, and cleaner to get rid of the +1 in
$1/1 + e^{-a_i}$, so we flip the division and subtract one,

$$  1 / P(x_i = 1 | x_j,j \ne i) = \frac{P(x^0) + P(x^1)}{P(x^1)} 
$$

$$= 
1 + \frac{ P(x^0)}{P(x^1)}
$$

Subtracting one, we get $\frac{ P(x^0)}{P(x^1)}$. On the original equation
we are also left with $e^{-a_i}$. Now it is enough to show $\frac{
  P(x^0)}{P(x^1)}$ equals to  $e^{-a_i}$.

$$ 
\frac{ P(x^0)}{P(x^1)} = \exp( x^{0^T}Wx^0 -   x^{1^T}Wx^1 )
$$

Using this equality

$$ x^TWx = \sum_{k,j} x_kx_jw_{kj} $$

If we define

$$  \sum_{k,j} \underbrace{x_kx_jw_{ij}}_{Y_{kj}} = \sum_{k,j}Y_{kj} $$

$$ 
= \sum_{k \ne i}\sum_j Y_{kj} + \sum_{j} Y_{ij}
$$

$$ 
= \sum_{k \ne i}( \sum_{j \ne i} Y_{kj} + Y_{ki}) + \sum_{j} Y_{ij}
$$

$$ 
= \sum_{k \ne i,j \ne i} Y_{kj} + \sum_{k \ne i}  Y_{ki} + \sum_{j} Y_{ij}
$$

$$ 
= \sum_{k \ne i,j \ne i} Y_{kj} + \sum_{k}  Y_{ki} + \sum_{j} Y_{ij} + Y_{ii}
$$

Let's use the equation above for $ \exp( x^{0^T}Wx^0 -   x^{1^T}Wx^1 )$

$$ 
\exp 
\big( 
\sum_{k}  Y_{ki}^0 + \sum_{j} Y_{ij}^0 + Y_{ii}^0 - 
( \sum_{k}  Y_{ki}^1 + \sum_{j} Y_{ij}^1 + Y_{ii}^1  )
\big)
 $$

$$ 
= \exp \big( 
0 - ( \sum_{k}  Y_{ki}^1 + \sum_{j} Y_{ij}^1 + Y_{ii}^1  ) 
\big)
 $$

$W$ is symmetric, then $\sum_{k}  Y_{ki}^1$ is the same as $\sum_{j}Y_{ij}^1$

$$ 
= \exp \big( 
- ( 2 \sum_{j} Y_{ij}^1 + Y_{ii}^1  ) 
\big)
 $$

$W$ is zero diagonal, so $Y_{ii}^1=0$,

$$ 
= \exp \big( 2 \sum_{j} Y_{ij}^1 \big) = \exp (- 2 a_i )
 $$

In the original equation there is $1/2$ which was not included in the
derivation, hence we get  $\exp (- a_i)$.

Answer (score 2):

Start from the fact that, for each $i$, the density of the full random vector $(X_j)_j$ can be factored as  $$P(X_i=x_i,\hat X_i=\hat x_i)=h(\hat x_i)\cdot\mathrm e^{a_i(x_i,\hat x_i)x_i},\qquad$$ for some positive function $h$ whose exact value is irrelevant, with $$\hat X_i=(X_j)_{j\ne i},\qquad\hat x_i=(x_j)_{j\ne i},\qquad a_i(x_i,\hat x_i)=\tfrac12w_{ii}x_i+\tfrac12\sum\limits_{j\ne i}(w_{ij}+w_{ji})x_j.$$ Hence, for every $\hat x_i$, $$P(X_i=1\mid\hat X_i=\hat x_i)=\frac{P(X_i=1,\hat X_i=\hat x_i)}{P(X_i=1,\hat X_i=\hat x_i)+P(X_i=0,\hat X_i=\hat x_i)}=\frac{\mathrm e^{a_i(x_i,\hat x_i)}}{\mathrm e^{a_i(x_i,\hat x_i)}+1}.$$
The formula for $a_i(x_i,\hat x_i)$ given in the question holds if $W=(w_{ij})_{ij}$ is symmetric ($w_{ij}=w_{ji}$) with zero diagonal ($w_{ii}=0$).

Comment: Symmetry condition just added to the question.

Comment: And now the zero diagonal condition...